# Modefiers Overloading

Tags: solidity, modifiers

Compiling this code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract OverloadModifier {
    uint public a = 0;
    bytes public b = 0x00;

    modifier m(uint _a) { _; }
    modifier m(bytes _b) { _; }

    function fa () public m(a) {}
    function fb () public m(b) {}
}
```

Throws this error:

```
DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
 --> OverloadModifier.sol:9:5:
  |
9 |     modifier m(bytes _b) { _; }
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: The previous declaration is here:
 --> OverloadModifier.sol:8:5:
  |
8 |     modifier m(uint _a) { _; }
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Assuming modifiers are technically 'functions' what prevents overloading them too? Wouldn't allowing overloading them be useful?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can overload a modifier in Solidity, but that would make the code hard to understand as the sole purpose of a Modifier is to be a standalone function that can be reused multiple times to check similar sorts of conditions.

Comment: I believe modifiers overloading is not allowed in solidity (currently v0.8.19. Do you mean there's 'technically' a way around it?). Check the code I added above for more context. Check this GitHub issue too: [link](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/72)